# Trying to check if there are any upper case, lowercase, non alphabetical letters in the input without the use of functions, but code not working

Tags: python, function

My code:

```
a=input()
    mylist.append(a)
for i in mylist:
    if i =='A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E' or 'F' or 'G' or 'H' or 'I' or 'J' or 'K' or 'L' or 'M' or 'N' or 'O' or 'P' or 'Q' or 'R' or 'S' or 'T' or 'U' or 'V' or 'W' or 'X' or 'Y' or 'Z':
        print("1",end='')
    else:
        print("0",end='')
        
    if i =='a' or 'b' or 'c' or 'd' or 'e' or 'f' or 'g' or 'h' or 'i' or 'j' or 'k' or 'l' or 'm' or 'n' or 'o' or 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 's' or 't' or 'u' or 'v' or 'w' or 'x' or 'y' or 'z':
        print("1",end='')
    else:
        print("0",end='')
```

My input:
{a}

Output:
{1111}

It doesn't matter if I input a uppercase or lowercase letter, It always outputs 1111.

I want it to output
{11}
for input
{a
A}

output
{01}
for input
{a}

I hope this made sense, its my first question here, sorry for any inclarities

Comment: have you cheked `string.isalpha()` `string.isupper()` `string.islower()`

Comment: He said without the use of functions so it's probably home work.

Comment: I suspect that you use  `or` in a way what is not your intention. Also, it is much simpler to use `if i in 'abc...xyz'` (or import constants from [string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get 4 print statements per loop then your print statements are not being evaluated conditionally.  Meaning they should be indented under the if statement (like your example shows).  The syntax for the if expression is wrong.  `i =='A' or 'B'` evaluates to either True or 'B'.  What you meant to write is `i == 'A' or i == 'B' ...`.

Try this for your loop body:

```
if 'A' <= i <= 'Z':
   print(1, end='')
elif 'a' <= i <= 'z':
   print(0, end='')
```

If your output is only letters than you get get way with this:

```
 print(int('A' <= i <= 'Z'))
```